# The question about $\tan$

Tags: trigonometry

I know if  $\tan(x) = 5$, $x=\tan^{-1}(5)$?

But if  $\tan(x) = 5^{-1}$, is $x=-\tan^{-1}(5)$?

Comment: You may be confusing the notation $^{-1}$ which indicates the [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function), with the same notation for the multiplicative inverse $5^{-1}=1/5$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $-1$ in $\tan ^{-1}(x)$ means the [inverse funtion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) (in an interval where it exists) of the **tangent** function, i.e the function **arctan** that is the arc ( angle) that has tangent $x$ (in a suitable interval).
The $-1$ in $5^{-1}$ means the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of $5$ in the field of real numbers: that is $5^{-1}=\frac{1}{5}$. So there is no relation between the meaning of the two exponents.

If $\tan x= 5^{-1}=\frac{1}{5}$ then, taking the inverse of the tan function, we have
$$
x=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=\mbox {arctan} \left(\frac{1}{5}\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

No. That is not how inverses work in general.

$x = \tan^{-1}(5^{-1})$

Answer (score 0):

No, $x=\arctan(5^{-1})=\arctan\left(\frac15\right)$.